# Custom map/direction CakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I'm totally new to CakePHP and not a PRO programmer, when i add my new map on my Server and write it like 
www.example.com/MyMap it give me an error like

```
Missing Controller
Error: AgendaController could not be found.

Error: Create the class AgendaController below in file: app/Controller/AgendaController.php

<?php
class AgendaController extends AppController {

}
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_controller.ctp
```

How can i make way to my new custom map

Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Cake lets you manually route things like this from `Agenda` to `MyMap` - use `Router::connect('/MyMap', array('controller' => 'agenda');`. More info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: I want to add another page to existing routering, so the map "Agenda" must be able when i go to Agenda

Comment: You don't add pages to the routing... Did even look at the blog tutorial in the CakePHP manual to understand the very basics of the framework?